# How to get the path to ringtones "/system/media/audio/ringtones" programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, path, directory, ringtone

I have device with some ringtones at /system/media/audio/ringtones by default.
I would like to get that path as programatically.I mean i would like to get the ringtones directory path from my device as programetically.

Comment: manually http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56905/where-is-the-default-ringtone-stored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to work with ringtones use [RingtoneManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html) because ringtones may be stored in few other directories. `RingtoneManager` gives you all possible ringtones from your device.
Check also http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#AccessingExtFiles and [DIRECTORY_RINGTONES](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_RINGTONES).

To directly answer your question there is no environment variable querying it you get the default ringtone directory.

Answer (score 1):

As of Android 2.2 you can use `DIRECTORY_RINGTONES` to get default ringtone directory

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_RINGTONES)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check [RingtoneManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html). getDefaultUri() method should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

Uri u = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "1");

i.setData(u);

startActivity(i);
```